# Startup Black Screen?

Tags: windows, installation

I just installed Blender and I'm new to all this.

When I open up Blender I see a black screen, like the command prompt app on Windows, and I was wondering how to get into Blender?
[image]

Then if I click on a space, as if I were selecting it, it goes to white:

[image]

Comment: Alfie, I wonder if you are being just a little impatient. When Blender first starts, the first thing one sees is a console window, and after a short time (the exact length of the short time seems to depend upon the hardware upon which Blender is installed, and depend further upon what other applications are running), Blender itself begins in a second window. I'd try again, and wait a little longer.

Comment: I have left it a few hours, re-opened it many times and still just a black screen. @brasshat

Comment: This looks like a graphics issue. What is your graphics card and system specs? Do you have any drivers installed? Are they up to date? Your computer may not be powerful enough to run blender

Comment: I have the same problem. I have been able to use blender for hours, and then later once I try to start it this happens. The black window never goes away and on my machine it is impossible to close the window, so it stays up until next reboot. Only solution I have found so far is to uninstall blender, and reinstall it. That worked for me. Unfortunately now the black window is back again. So reinstall is at best a temporary solution.

Comment: Usually when you get a corrupted screen like that is because of the graphics card not being configured correctly. What kind of graphics card are you using? A possible solution is to update the drivers, or if a newer driver is causing the issue, the downgrade to a previous version. To get a better idea of what is happening try running blender from a console, you might then a printout of the error. In windows, open a console (Windows key+R) then type cmd or cmd.exe. Navigate to the folder where blender is installed and type **blender.exe -con**

Comment: What Blender version are you using? Is it the official release from Blender.org?

Comment: This doesn't look like a graphics issue; this is only the console window that Python makes when starting programs. It looks like it might be a Python-related issue. Try different versions of Python if possible, perform reinstalls (of Blender and Python), and check compatibility.

Comment: Well, I just ran the compatibility Troubleshooter and it worked

Comment: Hello :). I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because it's either a [System Related Issue](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2762/78972) or a bug in Blender. You can use [This little guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173685/78972) to see whether it's a Bug that should be reported.