# Blender 2.8 will not open on my Windows 7 computer

Tags: error

I have been trying to upgrade to Blender 2.8 on my desktop.   However, when I black screen opens for a few seconds and closes.  My computer is a bit dated but should meet the minimum requirements.

My specs are:
Windows 7 home 64bit
Intel i7 920@2.6GHt
20Gb 2100MHz ddr3
ATI Radeon HD 4800 GPU (DirectX 9, 10.1)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer but I wonder if Blender abandoned support for Windows 7 since Microsoft themselves are ending support for it in 2020

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77895/startup-black-screen#comment138614_77895

Comment: @MrVimes - as long as it's not announced over the official channels, your comment is indeed not an answer.

Comment: Which AMD driver version do you have installed? Also, try to start Blender from the command line using the "--debug --debug-gpu" options, then update your question (by using the edit link below it) with the information it drops.

Comment: I have driver version 8.850.0.0

Comment: That's a fairly old version. The latest driver is 13.9

Comment: I just updated the drivers.  Now it opens the console, goes full screen, then freezes the computer...  Grr

Comment: @metaphor_set Hence why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.  I am simply suggesting it is a possibility.  Wondering.